# Repeating same data in row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why am I getting same value in all rows of table. Table has rows and when row is clicked another row opens with additional information and every row contains same data like last clicked row. Probably it is cos I am saving data in same object, but I really don't know how to solve it. I am getting data from `json` files with factor, so you don't get confused, where my data is coming from Here is the code. Thank you very much.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('sbAdminApp')
    .controller('TreeTableCtrl', TreeTableCtrl);

function TreeTableCtrl($scope, $http, factor) {

  
    function example() {
        factor.getUse().then(function (response) {
            $scope.users = response.data;
            console.log($scope.users);
        });
    }
    example();
    $scope.togglePerson = function (index) {
        factor.getChi().then(function (response) {
            $scope.indx = index;
            $scope.child = response.data;
            console.log($scope.child);
            $scope.childPar = $scope.child[index];
            console.log($scope.childPar);
        });
    };
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background: #fcf8e3">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table st-safe-src="leads" class="table table-hover  ">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="user in users track by $index" ng-init="parentIndex=$index"
                ng-click="togglePerson($index); viewChild=!viewChild ">
                <td> {{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="viewChild" ng-hide="indx!=$index" >
                <td style="width: 450px">
                    <table class="table ">

                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 200px">
                                Address
                            </th>
                            <td style="width: 200px">{{childPar.address}}</td>
                            <th style="width: 200px">
                                Number
                            </th>
                            <td style="width: 200px">{{childPar.mobNumb}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As `$scope.togglePerson` is declared in controller and you are referring same $scope prop's inside everychild .

Answer (score 0):

Of course its expected to be the same, you have only 1 property that handles the extra information which is the `$scope.childPar`

instead of doing that, manipulate your data that fits for your condition

Try this

```
function example() {
   factor.getUse().then(function (response) {
       //Remap the model, [data] -> user, [otherInfo] -> other info
       var users = response.data.map(function(value) { 
                       return { data: value, otherInfo: null }
                     });
       $scope.users = users;
       console.log($scope.users);
    });
}
example();
$scope.togglePerson = function (index) {
     factor.getChi().then(function (response) {
         $scope.indx = index;
         $scope.child = response.data;
         console.log($scope.child);
         //Populate the otherInfo from the response
         $scope.users[index].otherInfo = response.data;
         console.log($scope.childPar);
      });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background: #fcf8e3">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table st-safe-src="leads" class="table table-hover  ">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="user in users track by $index" ng-init="parentIndex=$index"
                ng-click="togglePerson($index); viewChild=!viewChild ">
                <td> {{user.data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.data.lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="viewChild" ng-hide="indx!=$index" >
                <td style="width: 450px">
                    <table class="table ">

                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 200px">
                                Address
                            </th>
                            <td style="width: 200px">{{user.otherInfo.address}}</td>
                            <th style="width: 200px">
                                Number
                            </th>
                            <td style="width: 200px">{{user.otherInfo.mobNumb}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```